# Vertically align text in reactable cells in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, react-table

Is there a way to vertically align (middle) the text in the cells in a reactable rendered within a shiny app?

minimal example below. I tried some CSS options but no luck so far.

```
library(shiny)
library(reactable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("reactable example"),
  reactableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- renderReactable({
    reactable(iris)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use defaultColDef to set default attributes. Below code snippet should vertically align text centrally:

```
library(shiny)
library(reactable)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("reactable example"),
    reactableOutput("table")
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$table <- renderReactable({
        reactable(iris, 
                  defaultColDef = colDef(
                      align = "center")
                  )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Below is the output after running the code. The output is both centrally & horizontally aligned

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply. That didn't work. It centered the text, but it didn't vertically align it. It still shows on top of the cell.

Comment: I have attached imaged of the output that I got. Text is both centrally & horizontally aligned.

Comment: you are right. there was a column with images on the real dataset I was that was messing the alignment.